# Find a string in the middle

Tags: code-golf, restricted-complexity, edit-distance

Given two strings \$A\$ and \$B\$ with edit (Levenshtein) distance \$x\$, find a third string with edit distance \$a\$ to \$A\$ and edit distance \$b\$ to \$B\$ so that \$a+b=x\$ and \$a=int(x/2)\$ (that is half of \$x\$ rounded down to the nearest integer).

The input is the two strings \$A\$ and \$B\$ and their edit distance \$x\$.  You don’t need to compute \$x\$.

\$A\$ is of length \$n\$ and \$B\$ is of length \$m\$ such that \$n/2 \le m \le n\$.

Your can take the input in any convenient format you like.

## Examples

```
Inputs: "hello", "hallo", 1. Output: "hello"

Inputs: "sitteng", "kitten", 2. Output: "sitten"

Inputs: "bijamas", "banana", 4. Output: "banamas"

Inputs: "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", "noultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", 6. Output: "umonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"
```

## Restriction

Your code must be run in \$O(n^2)\$ time where \$n\$ is the length of A.

Comment: Missing "...where N is X" for the restriction

Comment: @mousetail Better now?

Comment: You say "***A*** is of length ***n*** and ***B*** is of length ***n/2 ≤ m ≤ n***", however, you never defined ***m***, and ***B*** is certainly not half the length of ***A*** in the given examples...

Comment: @mbomb007 I edited it. Is that better?

Comment: @TheThonnu Yes, that looks correct.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>459</s> <s>514</s> 502 bytes

*+60 bytes, use correct initial condition*
*-11 bytes, thanks to ValueInk*
*-1 byte, thanks to c--*

```python
l=len
I=range
def f(s,t):
 m,n=l(s),l(t);w=m-~n;M=[[([t[:k]+s for k in I(j+1)],j)for j in I(n+1)]]+[[([s[k:]for k in I(i+2)],0)]+n*[0]for i in I(m)]
 for j in I(n):
  for i in I(m):D,d=M[i][j+1];U,u=M[i+1][j];R,r=M[i][j];a=l(D:=D+[p[:d]+p[d+1:]])if(p:=D[-1])[:d]==t[:d]else w;b=l(U:=U+[p[:u]+[t[j]]+p[u:]])if(p:=U[-1])[:u]==t[:u]else w;c=l(R:=R+[[],[p[:r]+[t[r]]+p[r+1:]]][p[r]!=t[r]])if(p:=R[-1])[:r]==t[:r]else w;M[i+1][j+1]={b:(U,u+1),c:(R,r+1),a:(D,d)}[min(a,b,c)]
 return(p:=M[m][n][0])[~-l(p)//2]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZPNbtwgEMfVq_sSTi6BmG2yOVVY3PaSw0rVSntCc8BeO8GLwQLcqKqaF-kll_ah-iA9d7DXSSpVUUHCzMfvDzPI338OX-K9s09PP8bYrj7-evfbCNPY7FZ4Ze-a7NC0eUsCi5Rnec-sMCRQZkik5YPoV4-23AopiYySH6EIeet8fsy1zW9JV6wpsI4mVze7bHJBkYAgjxxeZeviBrOvKRT2Ul5PET1HegpZ_lokXSX_K4Fv2EFspQaJh0K5Z2OycCs7KHfMn2JQKrz_hotNIQfJD1AM8lCsOQDVLRnQL1droCkiREyfxoQmfygrxPZc7CdsxAIiiiV6fGH3J3ac2XFha2R3XOywamCJ9xPvJ95PpwO6PZyJyXuS253k_CznF7mlLlzE14oTrBWbympOsM60U5xgN-g32WtLFKtYnfrnmzh6m4S3sgdpAXtM5ePKkIFeXd3A8vzvB69tJBcXHzqHfEuMDpGc3zfGuHN8-NlSk4Uj-3d60DE29u4ZOE72W0SlO9Wr8ExUyuJ8i_hkm7F31o0metXr2rtQu0HXQRtdu8_O1Mq62lntgn7R_e98HHNPll_jDw)

Input&Output as lists of characters.

*For some examples the result is different from the result in the question, but also satisfies the distance requirement*

### Explanation

Uses modified version of the [dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Iterative_with_full_matrix) for the computation of the Levenshtein distance.
Each cell stores the current prefix length and the path of all previous edits.
At the end the cell in the middle of the path is returned.

ungolfed code:

```python
def levDist(s,t):
  m,n=len(s),len(t)
  w=m+n+1 # one larger than the largest possible Levenshtein distance
  M=[]
  # initialize first row and column
  for i in range(0, m+1):
    M.append([([s[k:] for k in range(i+1)],0)]+[0]*n)
  for j in range(1, n+1):
    M[0][j]=([t[:k]+s for k in range(j+1)],j)
  for j in range(0, n):
    for i in range(0, m):
      # cell i,j -> shortest edit path that:
      # 1) only modifies the first i characters in s 
      # 2) ends with a word starting with the first j characters in t 
      D,d=M[i][j+1] # deletion
      U,u=M[i+1][j] # insertion
      R,r=M[i][j]   # substitution
      # for each edit type check if the previous cell contains the correct prefix and if yes perform the repetitive edit
      if (p:=D[-1])[:d]==t[:d]:
        D=D+[p[:d]+p[d+1:]]
        a=len(D)
      else:
        a=w
      if (p:=U[-1])[:u]==t[:u]:
        U=U+[p[:u]+[t[j]]+p[u:]]
        b=len(U)
      else:
        b=w
      if (p:=R[-1])[:r]==t[:r]:
        if p[r]!=t[r]:
          R=R+[p[:r]+[t[r]]+p[r+1:]]
        c=len(R)
      else:
        c=w
      x=min(a,b,c) # find operation with the shortest edit path
      if x==a:
        M[i+1][j+1] = (D,d)
      elif x==b:
        M[i+1][j+1] = (U,u+1)
      else:
        M[i+1][j+1] = (R,r+1)
  return ((p:=M[m][n][0])[(len(p)-1)//2],M[m][n]) # the ungolfed version also returns the complete edit path
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVSxbtswEJ269CuuySJWchJlKgyok8dmMeCJ4EBLJ5uORAokZcf9lS5Z2n9qv6ZHSo4c14UBC-I9vvfu8cQfv7qj3xr9-vqz9_Xsy58PuwpraHC_UM4nLvNs_hGgzXTRoE4cy8LDM1o7FG2q0xxuwWiERtoNWvBbqelvfHceOuOcWjcI33CP2m09Kg0VcUtdIrE8FVzQ4xaUVl7JRn1HqJWlndYcQOoKStP0rSZMbSwowoGVeoPJQwZtmkd7RHMnuw51lfCEO_48FxH9PKEVQUX2wETKH8RnzUa-3YTIM9ATH6H4ThQJ93z-LFJ3ybeLfLsrPORLjyxXHI-V0HGJTQMq28HsK7itsT7khZWi0KTfhij9BM4ZxdwcoTWVqhW6GPIQlIJyK60sPVoXxBy87XpkQKE4OCgilHAwtgKK3nqlN8PiRLO7oPEnmkVWFU9cUR5pLoi0wga9Mnosr7I-lKlGgcWDdGjP6svMjttF9OT6tfPK92eQ25gUynI79O-PHZIbLCnwOlrsLO6V6d0QWmm0l6QTS6WxFksfILV6iSNDm44UUYeWeNuIstiRaa_2GCVGYQIm3bxY8FkuGJ9Xoih8eJxyp-aLRcq7sJZ2vErzuRBvNRm_iQUbF7BxOD8rHt6LrEaRfhDpz0RWxSqK9DSdnnIKWv250joqra4rrS-VlqOSHZTsmRIhOm7FJ1o_X6ZTKpbRgo0WbLRg37dbRhPL6ybKNxMvRat0IrN1VrJwsooOxNBRyHDg09D9O_FTEy9FISfq03CF6SsgoXGcLAzg9X_BNJz0oV51fIGkMR2QFn1vNSQhySfeCq4FXQaMJ6H7js1ydn__KLKxFFoM7fR6Y5oaK9jT5xMalY0zI9dpTtuOPhycGh6u3N93nVXaJ6c7twl_N2u1k610N3ThDu9S0--GMTbsOl3YfwE)

Comment: This is a very nice solution.

Comment: Can you explain more about the initial condition fix?

Comment: @Simd In the old version the edit distance for the last example was wrong (7 instead of 6). The new initial condition corresponds to the edits that are used in the initial condition of the distance algorithm.

Comment: `~-l(p)//2` to save 2 bytes

Comment: I just double checked and Python dict allows for duplicate keys during declaration (the lattermost will take precedence) which means you should be able to do `{a:(D,d),b:(U,u+1),c:(R,r+1)}[min(a,b,c)]` instead of the `index` strategy for -9.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>182</s> 175 bytes, not in \$O(n^2)\$

*-7 bytes thanks to [@Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)*

```haskell
import Data.List
l=length
(x:w)#(y:z)|x==y=map(x:)$w#z
a@(x:w)#b|y:z<-b=sortOn l[a:w#b,a#z++[b],a:map(y:)(w#z)]!!0|1>0=a:w#[]
_#(y:z)=[]#z++[y:z]
_#_=[[]]
a%b=b#a!!div(l$b#a)2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVPRatswFIU96itu4rZIRA5J1sEwUdjDxhgU9gFCpFert3i13KzSGjvkT_rSl7LHfc_2NbuyHa-ljoPOPefcK3GvfP9rg_46L8uHh8ef4Wv69s_vwm1vbgO8x4DTi8IHVqoyr76FDeN1thMJb7K9ONRKNcrhljhxskv2DN91sj2Qvkyt8lTlcwWlxmyXWInJfjLR1kjMYlqTCU5pwoxGs8N8NVPRpQ1bd_WVNq2fcOTWSmtjGJ5aZRMcja6KO16eEBSL7th_X310RfUasgw-VQHS1cuFtQYFnFaYCpgCAcbK_C5mffgBCGoFGk3090tMiwZt4qtgdozokI0XxMxhAj3X-FalNtQktf6jWnuKn6p9_gFqUAoasva250WebdOen_e-ThFd3LujlQ91BGMh9-EL-txTBc2AHj7e0LBvxhLGG-zAPOKWFLL3-CIEGnl0XbeQ0IKCjv_vs8V3dOijz2JFP0LnfRD5wThsSv83cRmU8bD7UWkFw5hDmpOC7W1BI9TcybZFCK7vqQMbe9eRFs7OBv0Je0k35RIWsdMcJVgJVxLWApYpDM2R4JapRjgFS3esu0_Hz-Ef)

---

Edit: I remembered that the Levenshtein distance could be calculated in quadratic time, but I didn't remember *which* algorithm was the one with this time complexity and I didn't bother to check the complexity of the naive one.

Comment: Thanks for giving the first answer!

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by replacing `head` with `!!0`.

Comment: You can also combine the 4th and 6th lines into `a@(x:w)#b|y:z<-b=sortOn l[a:w#b,a#z++[b],a:map(y:)(w#z)]!!0|1>0=a:w#[]`, to save 5 more bytes.

Comment: Are you sure this runs in quadratic time?

Comment: I fear your code might take exponential time. Try it with strings of length 50 to 100.

Comment: I added a test case where your code does not terminate.

Comment: Can you use https://wiki.haskell.org/Edit_distance. ?